# VBA with type mismatch

Tags: excel

Good morning I'm trying to apply this code to run a macro and find values in a large excel table.
But there is a problem in this line: "If c.Value = cell Then " when I run it it says Error 13 Type mismatch.
Can someone try this code and tell me why is that error happening.
Thanks a lot.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm7.Hide
     
    Dim c, r As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sheet As String: sheet = UserForm6.TextBox3.Value
    Dim val As String: val = TextBox3.Value
    Dim range_to_filter As Range: Set range_to_filter = Range("B4:S4")
    
        While val = " " Or val = ""
            MsgBox ("Please insert a valid PartNumber")
            UserForm7.Show
            
        Wend
    
        Sheets(sheet).Activate
         
        With Sheets(sheet)
        
         Set cell = .Cells.Find(What:=val)
       
            For Each c In Range("B4:S20000")
                
             If c.Value = cell Then
                   c.Interior.ColorIndex = 20
                   i = i + 1
            Else
        End If
        
         Next c
                
                MsgBox i & " PartNumbers were found", vbInformation, "PartNumbers Found"
                 range_to_filter.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=cell
        
                
        End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code compares ```c.Value``` (a String or Number) with ```cell``` (a Range) so type mismatch is to be expected here. What data are you trying to actually compare ?

Comment: Here are some basics. In `Dim sheet As String: sheet = UserForm6.TextBox3.Value`. `Sheet` is an object and shouldn't be used as a variable name. It should also not be a string because it's a sheet. Never use a colon to separate lines. Instead, separate lines into separate lines. `Dim val As String: val = TextBox3.Value` - ditto - and `Val` is a VBA function. If it does run it will certainly cause confusion to the reader which, mostly, will be yourself. Finally, list `Dim` statements before and above the code, not intermingled with the code. The effect of the mix is that neither is clear.

Comment: It seems you want to loop through an excel database (containing ```PartNumber```), highligh cells that match your search and display the number of matching cells. But be carefull, ```Find``` method only returns the first cell where you have a match. So ```cell``` variable will always contain only 1 address. You should loop though your cells only with the ```For Each``` statement, compare ```c.Value = val```, and filter your data based on your cell color. Also add a line ```.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = default_color``` otherwise highlighted cells will just stack up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) function returns:

> A Range object that represents the first cell where that information
> is found

You are comparing the [Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) object of type variant to an object of type `Range`.
Change your code to:

```
  If c.Value = cell.Value
```